# How to make text in entry widget save to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm very new to Python as a whole, let alone Tkinter. I'm wondering if it's possible to have the text entered in my entry widget save to a variable so I can run it in a ping script and then have the label display the result.

```
import Tkinter

class pinger(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="EW")
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Ping",command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label= Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky="EW")
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Enter a hostname to begin")


        self.resizable(False,False)

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (Button clicked)" )

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (Enter Pressed)" )



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = pinger(None)
    app.title('Server Pinger')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are already doing so when you `set` the `labelVariable`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You'll have to excuse me if this is a dumb question, but how would I then go about using it in other instances? For example if I wanted to print what was entered into the entry widget would I just 'print(self.entryVariable)'? Sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: You would [use `self.entryVariable.get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thank you!